# Python function from C++ program

Tags: python, c++, csv

Below is the logic program of the program I am trying to implement.

```
#include -libraries-
{
   int num,  //Number of rows in the CSV file

   for(i=1; i<=num, i++)
   {
       //Call python function
       //Input to python function - row number
       //It has to return elements from that particular row
   }

}

def row_elements(num):
{
   //Read CSV file
   //Use Pandas package to fetch the data from CSV file
}
```

Can anybody please suggest me with an example how this could be implemented.

Thank you.

Comment: There are two basic options here: (1) [Embed the CPython interpreter in your C++ app](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html#embedding-the-cpython-runtime-in-a-larger-application), or (2) Run the CPython interpreter on your script as a child process of your C++ app, passing arguments and return values over command line args, stdin/stdout, pipes, or files in known locations.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is being done in C++ when it looks like the Python code is doing all the heavy lifting?

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the links. Will check and let you know if any queries. 
IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yea. That was just a part of code, and after accessing CSV data it needs to be passed to one more module which supports C++. The whole project is in C++.